# Unable to add some Github projects to my careers.SE profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

When adding projects in the "Open Source" section, the GitHub page only lists projects I currently have an active fork of. I have no way to add projects that I've been allowed read/write access to but don't own or have an active fork of. I've also tried copying/pasting the link into the "other" form at which point I'm told I can't add that project and should use the GitHub page.

I'm specifically trying to add [casascius/Bitcoin-Address-Utility](https://github.com/casascius/Bitcoin-Address-Utility). It's easily visible that I've pushed legitimate commits to this project but I have no way to list it on my careers.SE page.